# JuiceUI-draggable how to get new item position?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, juice-ui

I'm trying to get (and store) new position of a dynamically added panels to my page.
These panels are surcharged with a Juice:Draggable plugin.
The panels ids are saved in viewstate to maintain some properties (color, size,...) and it works well!

My only problem is that I can't get new position when clicking a "Save" button. Even if the panels are recreated with the same id, they don't seem to get the last position when the page reload...?

Could this be solved without mastering ajax/javascript (as I only know asp.net)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The position are keep on `left` and `top` variables of the style of the dragged item. Now from the moment that all that done via automation of the Juiceui I think is better first contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're tracking a fix for this at https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/issues/22 Please keep an eye on that and @juiceui on twitter for a fix and release announcement, respectively.